# automatically activate service after RPM was installed

Tags: systemd, rpm, services, systemd-unit, rpm-spec

OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8

I've created a `.spec` file to build and package my application. My `rpm` also includes `my_app.service` file for `systemd` to start it. However, by default one has to enable this with `systemctl enable my_app.service`. I'd like to have it enabled after the `rpm` has been installed. I've googled and found that I can use [systemd.preset](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html), which says:

> It is not recommended to ship preset files within the respective software packages implementing the units, but rather centralize them in a distribution or spin default policy, which can be amended by administrator policy.

Does it mean I should not be adding `.preset` file in my rpm? Also, later in the `man` page it says:

> If no preset files exist, systemctl preset will enable all units that are installed by default.

If I read it correctly, then my application's service file should be automatically enabled, but it is not happening, or this implies the manual `systemctl preset` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean I should not be adding .preset file in my rpm?

Yes, you shouldn't put the .preset file in your service's package RPM

> but it is not happening

It's not happening because the `systemd` package in RHEL ships with a default preset at `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-systemd.preset`.

If you want to stick to distribution packaging guidelines you have two options, namely:

- contact operating system's packager for including your application service to the default preset
- more feasible, create your own package for shipping preset. typically you ship your preset in your own repository's "release" package. An example of this is `epel-release`, which installs `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-epel.preset` among other things.

Comment: thanks for feedback! What priority value should I put in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/<priority>-myapp.preset` file? The larger the value, the lower the priority? (man systemd.preset is not very specific about this)

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd assume the higher number is the higher priority. As in alphabetical/numerical order, the priority `99` would override `10` thus having higher priority.

Comment: So, I've added `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/99-default-myapp.preset` and added `enable myapp.service` line in it. My file is in lexicographic order and should be pulled in the last. After reboot, I was expecting to see `systemctl status myapp.service` would show `... vendor preset: enabled`, however it has not happened. What am I missing?

Comment: After I renamed `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/99-default-myapp.preset` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/98-default-myapp.preset` it works. I still don't understand why `99-default-myapp.preset` does not get picked up after `99-default-disable.preset`, although _alphabetically_ `99-default-myapp.preset` is the last one.